# JFreeChart tooltip unexpected residue

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, jfreechart

My Java Swing application is making use of (the excellent) JFreeChart library but unfortunately there is an unexpected behavior: when hovering the mouse over a chart's datapoint, a customized tooltip is shown (as expected); however, after that there is a constant tooltip residue next to the mouse cursor when it is on the chart but not on a datapoint anymore (i.e. no tooltip should appear anymore).

Hereby a picture that shows the residue (grey dot at to the bottom right of the mouse cursor - it looks like the borders of an empty tooltip):

[image]

The residue "follows" the mouse position and if I change application (e.g. alt-tab) and then come back, the residue disappeared.
Did someone experience the same problem? Any idea how to solve this?

Technical details:

- I'm using latest JFreeChart version (1.0.19)
- My application is using a specific UI L&F manager but this doesn't seem to be the problem as the residue is also present without it (UI manager set as `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SubstanceTwilightLookAndFeel())`
- The problem is present on `XYLineChart` and on `BarChart`
- Tooltips are customized (i.e. implemented `XYToolTipGenerator` interface where `generateToolTip()` returns HTML with the tooltip content)
- Tooltip delay is set to minimum (`ChartPanel.setInitialDelay(0)`) and dismiss delay to maximum (`ChartPanel.setDismissDelay(Integer.MAX_VALUE)`)

Many thanks for any help or hint as I've been stuck on this for hours now!
Thomas

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [short, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your effect in case I implement a `XYToolTipGenerator` generator that returns an empty string (`""`) instead of `null` in case the tooltip should not be shown.

Please ensure that your `XYToolTipGenerator` implementation returns a non empty string or `null` in the `generateToolTip()` method.

Comment: The method always returns a non-empty string since it is only called (I believe) when the mouse is on a datapoint. The problem occurs when the mouse is not on a datapoint (in which case method generateToolTip(dataset, row, column) is not called. Thx anyway !